# How to write an interface type adapter for gson without infinite recursion/stackoverflow

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to write a generic handler for de/serializing interfaces using Gson and getting stack overflow.  I've followed a couple of examples at https://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html and https://paul-stanescu.medium.com/custom-interface-adapter-to-serialize-and-deserialize-interfaces-in-kotlin-using-gson-8539c04b4c8f (which seem to be duplicates of each other).  If I run these, serializing a simple class, I get stack overflow. I'm using Gson 2.8.5.  I guess its fairly clear that it is trying to call the type adapter again when trying to get the value for the DATA element.  Searched around, but haven't seen anything.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class InterfaceAdapter<INTERFACE> implements JsonSerializer<INTERFACE>, JsonDeserializer<INTERFACE> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME";
    private static final String DATA = "DATA";

    public INTERFACE deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonPrimitive prim = (JsonPrimitive) jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME);
        String className = prim.getAsString();
        Class<INTERFACE> klass = getObjectClass(className);
        return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonObject.get(DATA), klass);
    }

    
    public JsonElement serialize(INTERFACE jsonElement, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty(CLASSNAME, jsonElement.getClass().getName());
        jsonObject.add(DATA, jsonSerializationContext.serialize(jsonElement));
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public Class getObjectClass(String className) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public static class Dummy {
        int a= 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Dummy.class, new InterfaceAdapter()).create();
        Dummy d = new Dummy();
        String json = gson.toJson(d);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first link promotes a vulnerable practice that allows deserializing an arbitrary class whitelisting all classes by default. Additionally, it totally ignores the `Type` parameter that contains type information whilst `Class` only represent a class loaded by JVM (no type information, whatever), so the second item demonstrates how the source promotes a wrong and insufficient approach. Anyway, I don't care analyzing that solution further.

Comment: Also, note that you're running into infinite recursion because you're trying serializing an object of the _same type_ again and again. `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` have limited functionality, and for the former you need to serialize the value _yourself_ (yeah, populating your JSON tree _yourself_, field by field using `JsonSerializationContext` unless it reaches the very end), because `JsonSerializationContext` does not let you access the type adapter you're trying to override.

Comment: What you're looking for is `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` that can be found in the Gson extras source code: 1) it uses whitelist-only strategy promoting type aliases not letting arbitrary/untrusted types to be deserialized; 2) it uses JSON streams rather than JSON trees for performance reasons; 3) it uses the delegate type adapter to get the "default" adapter not running into infinite recursion; 4) don't trust any published Maven artifact to contain the "extras" -- they are unofficial therefore untrusted (copy `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` from the Gson codebase, it **is** fine).